# catch response from call

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, foreach, compiler-errors

I am getting this error in my foreach statement.

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type because does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.
```

What does it means and how may i solve this?

**UPDATE**

Here is some code:

```
    ServiceReference.TimereportResponseDto[] response;
    foreach (ServiceReference.TimereportResponseDto r in response)
    arbu.Text += r.Message + " " + r.Id + Environment.NewLine;
```

Added **[ ]** to the first lite and now i am getting another error:

```
Use of unassigned local variable 'response'
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have this documentation example where it looks like this:

```
Gateway.TimereportResponseDto[] response = theGate.CreateTimereport(timeReport); 
foreach (Gateway.TimereportResponseDto r in response) 
textBoxLog.Text += r.Message + " " + r.Id + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Can you provide the code please?

Comment: The variable you are "foreaching" over is not a collection. Can you post more code ?

Comment: Make sure that the variable you are trying to iterate over has a public method called "GetEnumerator".

Comment: If you looking for an answer ask a question and provide details

Comment: The second error is because you haven't initialized `response` with anything. The error code is pretty descriptive..

Comment: "*Use of unassigned local variable*" means you are trying to *use* the response before it's been assigned (from the snippet you have in your example - that looks like the case).

Comment: Changed the title. I want to catch a response from a call if its making any sense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that you cannot do `foreach` on your desired object, since it does not expose a `GenEnumerator`-method, implemented by `IEnumerable` (`IEnumerable<T>`). Seems it is no Collection-object.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx):

IEnumerable-interface

```
Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a non-generic collection.
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not iterating over object which implements (`IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`), *(e.g.  an array or list )*

[foreach - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each
>   element in an array or an object collection **that implements the
>   `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` interface**.

Answer (score 2):

From *[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ttw7t8t6.aspx)*;

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each
>   element **in an array** or an **object collection that implements the
>   System.Collections.IEnumerable or
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable interface**.

Looks like you should impelement [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface in your class.